# .htaccess add text after variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Motive:** I am building my own simple cms. But when doing htaccess for my posts I am stuck when I want to add text after the id passing in url.

What i have tried so far is:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ post.php?id=$1
```

The problem is that when I type in `http://example.com/blog/1` I get the post returned. but when I go to `http://example.com/blog/1/hello-world` its not working.
I want the text hello-world added to permalinks for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below RewriteRule working fine for me.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/(.*)?$ blog_detail.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The title I want will be retrieved from data base and I don't need that as variable.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt but that's the other way around ;) A rewrite rule parses the URI when it's coming in, getting the title from the database (your `hello-world` part in your example) is only relevant when you are _creating_ the uri's (when you are constructing a link for instance)

Comment: One addition to this: you should consider to make the slug unique in your database and omit the id altogether; an url like `/blog/1/hello-world` is a three-level url, while `/blog/hello-world` is a two-level url. Search engines consider a two-level url more important. And as you are checking the id AND the slug anyway, you don't really need the id (you probably do need it internally though, so don't remove the column from your database)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to writing regex in .htaccess, you could also route all of URLs to one PHP script, like Wordpress does:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
```

Then, inside index.php you can split $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to parts and process as you wish, like this:

```
$parts = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($parts[1]==="blog")
{
    $id = intval($parts[2]);
    include("post.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Another great solution but as question suggests I want it through htaccess rewrite.

Comment: But this _is_ .htaccess rewrite ;p

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt - yes, I agree.  I just noticed that you're writing your own CMS, so perhaps taking the routing logic into PHP would be more convenient, than configuring it in .htaccess all the time.  Easy to forget to change, harder to install, etc.

Comment: I have built more than half of it added all post.php edit.php page.php and etc.php... so can't modify now.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt You can incorporate the routing change to index.php only. Other scripts don't need changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'ugly' url does not use the title, you can simply match it, but ignore it. You are currently matching `1/hello-world` in your first capture group, and your post.php page can obviously not handle this. Instead match the following:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/[^/]+$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Edit: Someone claims that this approach is inefficient. I beg to differ. You can do the following in php to redirect requests that were done using an incorrect url. It's exactly as efficient as a comparison of `$_GET['title']` and `$expectedtitle`, then constructing the url. The difference is that you have no useless variables lying around, and the intention of this code is clear. You want to redirect the user if the url is not the expected url. That the expected title is not the actual title is a sideproduct.

```
$expectedtitle = getTitleById( $_GET['id'] );
$expectedurl = "{$_GET['id']}/{$expectedtitle}";
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $expectedurl ) {
  header( $expectedurl, TRUE, 301 );
}
```

Comment: so what I need to modify is just adding a + before $

Comment: You'll have to be really careful with this, because `/blog/1/hello-world` and `/blog/1/bye-world` will both be matched and both return the same post, resulting in duplicate content... So you'll have to cross your fingers search engines will not find out about other possible url's

Comment: No i will add canonical tags to head adding post title with spaces str_replace'd with '-'.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt No; if you add a + before the $ in your rule the capture group will still be greedy and gobble up all characters.

Comment: @giorgio That's something mod_rewrite has no part in. That's something blog.php should do based on `%{REQUEST_URI}` as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Sumurai8 oh got you.

Comment: @Sumurai8 but as you just ignore the extra part, instead of pass it to post.php, the script will never know what string is used, and will not be able to reject or show the post based on the slug. So you should pass the slug as well in a second query parameter. Or it should parse the URI from the `$_REQUEST` var. But if you do that, why would you want a separate rewrite rule for posts? Why not use a front controller with internal routes?

Comment: @giorgio I just want a solution that is better and fast. Can you suggest one.

Comment: Yup, the one @Chauhan gave below

Comment: @giorgio Sorry, I should have said `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, not `%{REQUEST_URI}`. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will contain the original url used for the request, not the rewritten one.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yeah but all the same; you're doing work twice... first let mod_rewrite parse and rewrite the url, then in the script you'll have to parse the url yet again... If you're using the power of the rewrite module anyway, better use the full power of it

Comment: @giorgio It makes no difference if you pass a title variable to the script and compare that, or if you construct the url that you expect in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and redirect to it if it does not match. There is really no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @giorgio See my edit. It even works magically if someone would request `blog.php?id=1254`.

Comment: Yeah but I wasn't talking about efficiency in terms of computer speed or whatever, but it's just conceptually wrong. I haven't even used the word efficiency... What you're doing now is writing a tiny front-end controller for just the posts, meaning you're doing 'calculations' on the uri on two different places... What if you decide to omit the id altogether? Then you'll have to change the logic on two places. Talking about efficiency right? So either complete the rewrite rule, or use a proper front-end controller which will do all calculations. This is a half-solution.

Comment: With all 3 answers you would need to change the logic in 2 places. If you use a php router, which would be the next best thing, you need to make the router aware how to get a title from an id. You need to change post.php and the router to make things work. Is that what you want? No, not really. Chauhan's answer like you suggested makes no difference whatsoever. You still need to change the logic 'in 2 places'. Arguably this would be easier, because you just have to think "how do I construct the correct url", not "what differences could be between the expected url and the actual url".

Comment: '+1' for the 301 redirect you given